# Collect colours to array from has many array in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, activerecord

I have a `Product` which `has_many :product_attributes`

The schema for `ProductAttribute` is the following:

```
product_id :integer
key :string
value :string
```

A Product belongs to a Category and what I would like to do is `Category.find(1).all_colours` which would collect all the colours (`.where(key: 'Colour')`) and allow me to `.each` through them in a list and removing and duplicates.

An example record for a `ProductAttribute` would be:

Colour: Blue, Green, Red, Orange, Blue

I'm using the following method:

```
def all_colours
  products.collect {|p| p.product_attributes.where(key: 'Colour').map(&:value) }.uniq
end
```

But it returns the following:

```
[["Green, Blue, Red, Orange, Green", "Purple, Teal, Ruby"]]
```

I would like the result to:

- Create array based off the array above, removing any duplicates and flattening.

The right result from the above should be...

```
['Green', 'Blue', 'Red, 'Teal', 'Ruby', 'Purple']
```

I'm hoping somebody can point me in the right direction with this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
products.collect {|p| p.product_attributes.where(key: 'Colour').map(&:value) }.join(', ').split(', ').uniq
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the flatten method to concat multi dimensional arrays into 1 array

```
def all_colours
  products.collect {|p| p.product_attributes.where(key: 'Colour').map(&:value).split(', ') }.flatten.uniq.join(", ")
end
```

Comment: That will flatten the array but still has an array and doesn't remove any duplicates.

Comment: I seem to have missed from my question the intended result. While that answers some part I would like to create an array based off these results, splitting and joining by a comma and removing duplicates.

Comment: Review my question above, I've added an expected result. Thanks :)